# How To Generate a Report for a survey

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

Okay, so I have never used reports in MS Access before so I am having some issues. If there are any similarities to forms I am very familiar with those.

What I am trying to do is to autogenerate a report when someone inputs a SurveyID. I have two tables with the following fields:

tbl_Questions with fields [QuestionID (Primary Key), Question, SurveyID]

tbl_Answers with fields [AnswerID(Primary Key), QuestionID, Answer]

When someone inputs a SurveyID I want the report to display the Question and then iterate through and display all Answers that share that Question's QuestionID. I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Of note: I am using MS Access 2003 =(

Comment: I have tried unsuccessfully to write a giant sql command that combines all values that I want to display as well as a count of each distinct answer but I couldn't get the count correctly because I couldn't iterate through.

Comment: I need to be able to manually specify the data so that I can select the first question, then iterate through all answers, then move on to the second question, etc.

Comment: Counts and percentages and totals don't need to be in the source SQL -- you can use sorting/grouping in the report for that. Just have your recordsource produce the single records that you'd display if you were writing a detail report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider solving some intermediate tasks:

1. Create a report with necessary data.
2. Create a form button to print/preview the report.
3. Change button code to print/preview the report, but for this ID only. Filters are nice.
4. Identify the code that saves the new ID.
5. Execute the print/preview code in #3 in #4.

Not ideal, but an excellent lesson. You can research these tasks or ask a specific question on SO if you can't find it.